# No puedo almacenar valor del Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una duda y es que quiero almacenar el valor de un `Entry` como un entero y este a su vez almacenarlo en un diccionario, pero el valor del `Entry` me da error.
Lo que quiero es que el usuario ingrese un código de barras y tras darle a aceptar guarde ese código de barras (Es para crear una base de datos). Lo exporto en un `.txt` con `json`.
Todo funciona bien, pero el valor del código de barras no lo coge bien.
Adjunto el código:

```
from tkinter import *
import json

raiz = Tk()

numerodelcb=StringVar()
subventana = Frame() 
#----------CÓDIGO DE BARRAS-----------------------
Codigobarras = Label(subventana, text="Código de barras: ")
Codigobarras.grid(row=10,column=0)

numeropantallacb = Entry(subventana,textvariable=numerodelcb) 
numeropantallacb.grid(row=10,column=1)

def aceptar():
    global valorCB 
    if numerodelcb!="":
        valorCB=int(numerodelcb.get())

def escribir():
    informacion={"Codigo de barras":valorCB,"Anio":2021}
    with open("Informacion.txt","w") as bbdd:
        json.dump(informacion,bbdd)

boton = Button(subventana, text="Aceptar",command=[aceptar(),escribir()])
boton.grid()
raiz.mainloop()
```

Si a `valorCB` le doy un valor fijo como: `valorCB=35` lo que se escribe en el archivo `.txt` es esto:

```
{"Codigo de barras": 35, "Anio": 2021}
```

No obstante, si le doy el valor: `valorCB=int(numerodelcb.get())` (que es lo que busco)
Me sale el error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: y si vas a trabajar con enteros ¿por qué no declarar directamente asi?: numerodelcb=IntVar()

Comment: Tienes razón con lo que comentas, no me había percatado. De todas formas un compañero ya me ha dado la solución. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código tiene dos problemas, los cuales solucionaré en esta respuesta.

#### Primer Problema

Primero que nada, sabías que las funciones aceptar y escribir se llaman apenas tu boton es creado?
Me dirás "A que se debe esto?". Pues se debe a que estás llamando las funciones en esta linea:

```
boton = Button(subventana, text="Aceptar",command=[aceptar(),escribir()])
```

El parametro command del botón espera que le pases un objeto función (las funciones también son objetos). Al poner los parentesis a la derecha de la función, la estás llamando. Si quieres ejecutar más de una función, vas a tener que crear otra función que llame a ambas funciones.

Puedes hacerlo así con una función "normal":

```
def aceptar_y_escribir():
    aceptar()
    escribir()

# Notese que paso la función sin los parentesis, ya que si no llamaría a la función apenas el boton es creado.
boton = Button(subventana, text="Aceptar",command=aceptar_y_escribir)
```

O con una [función lambda](https://borjauria.medium.com/que-son-y-como-utilizar-lambdas-en-python-4d1d168e2f90) así:

```
# Hago que cuando el lambda se ejecute cree una tupla con el resultado de las dos funciones a llamar.
boton = Button(subventana, text="Aceptar",command=lambda:(aceptar(),escribir()))
```

#### Segundo Problema

Cuando la función aceptar es ejecutada, pones a prueba la siguiente condición:

```
if numerodelcb!="":
```

Aquí estás diciendo, hacé x cosa si el stringvar no es igual a una cadena vacía. Esto es SIEMPRE cierto, por que un objeto de tipo stringvar nunca va a ser igual a una cadena vacía. Como la condición da verdadero cuando el entry está vacío, tu código intenta convertir dicha cadena vacía en un entero, y una cadena vacía no es un número.

En pocas palabras, incluso solucionando el primer problema, si el entry está vacio y le das aceptar, el código de tu función aceptar es equivalente a:

```
global valorCB

if(True):
    valorCB = int('')
```

Supongo que lo que deseabas hacer era saber si el entry está vacío. Para eso vamos a usar el método get del StringVar. Que como supongo que sabrás, nos permitirá obtener el contenido del entry.

En base a esto, la función aceptar quedaría así:

```
def aceptar():
    global valorCB 
    if numerodelcb.get()!="":
        valorCB=int(numerodelcb.get())
```

Sin embargo, hay algo que no tienes trabajado en tu código, y es que sucede si el entry está vacío. Tu función escribir daría un error debido a que la variable valorCB no existiría. Pero supongo que eso es algo que harás por ti mism@ después. Yo solo te aviso que eso pasará.

Comment: Maravillosa explicación. Me ha quedado bastante claro y he conseguido solucionarlo. Soy nuevo con este apartado de Python y aún me cuesta. Lo del error que comentas ya lo había intuido, pero quería primero solucionar esto para ponerme con ello. No obstante quisiera preguntarte otra cosa y es que ahora en la ventana del Entry me aparece por defecto un 0. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que no aparezca nada y que esté vacía por defecto? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Gracias c: Supongo que hiciste lo que dijo Tincopasan. El problema con la idea de Tincopasan es que si el entry está vacío e intentas obtener el valor del intvar, va a suceder un error. Te recomiendo volver al StringVar, que por defecto está vacío y no te dará ese error.

Comment: Efectivamente estás en lo cierto jajaja. Gracias de nuevo, ahora sí queda todo zanjado ^^